# api.export() seems to be not working after updating meteor to version 1.2.1.

Tags: meteor, export, package

I use api.export() to export data in meteor package prior to version 1.2.1 it was working fine but after updating to 1.2.1 its not working anymore.

```
Package.on_use(function (api) { 
    api.export("<somedata>", 'client');
}
```

Comment: Can you show a more complete, reproducible example? Please show an example variable, the way you add, define and export it, and the way you expect to use it outside the context of the package.

Comment: Actually it seems to be error case with less package version as meteor imposed some new constraints with less package, after fixing issue with less package, I'm not able to reproduce this issue.